# How to implementation parcelable for List<data class> (child list) in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, mvvm, parcelable

I want to intent data class to other activity with parcelable. But I have stuck when i want to intent variabel type List. I don't know how to implementation because it's first time for me using parcelable

This is my POJO/ Models

```
@Parcelize
data class HistoryTree(
val id: Int,
val landOwner: String,
val treeNumber: String,
val membershipId: String,
val speciesId: Int,
val speciesName: String,
val diameter: Double,
val areaName: String,
val woodProducts: List<HistoryProduct>) :Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class HistoryProduct(
val id: Int,
val treeId: Int,
val logStatus: Int,
val orderId: Int,
val logSequenceNumber: Int,
val logNumber: String,
val diameter: String,
val length: String,
val circumference: String,
val logType: Int,
val statusPecah: Int?,
val lubangGerek: Int?,
val pinhole: Int?,
val belimbing: Int?,
val createdBy: Int,
val deleted: Int,
val isTake: Int,
val rejectStatusPetani: Int
) : Parcelable
```

This my Activity

```
package com.sobi.penebangan.historylist
class HistoryListActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
private lateinit var job: Job
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

private val vm: HistoryListViewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(HistoryListViewModel::class.java) }

private var trees = mutableListOf<HistoryTree>()

private val treeAdapter = object : RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryItemViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HistoryItemViewHolder {
        val ui = HistoryItemUi()
        val view = ui.createView(AnkoContext.create(parent.context, parent))
        return HistoryItemViewHolder(ui, view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = trees.size



    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HistoryItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(trees[position]) {
            val product = it.woodProducts
            val activity = Intent(this@HistoryListActivity, ProductHistoryListActivity::class.java)
            activity.putExtra(ProductHistoryListActivity.paramTreeNumber, it.treeNumber)
            activity.putExtra(ProductHistoryListActivity.paramHistoryData, it.woodProducts)
            startActivity(activity)

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error when i want to intent variable woodProduct because type data is List

Anyone can help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50152749/4168607

Comment: Thank u. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity, while adding list data to intent cast to `ArrayList<out Parcelable>`

ex:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("arrayList",it.woodProducts as 
ArrayList<out Parcelable>)
```

Then in the second activity while getting data cast it to ArrayList

ex:

```
    val list =  intent.extras
    val prodList: List<HistoryProduct> = list?.get("arrayList") as ArrayList<HistoryProduct>
```